# 3d Cloud Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

подскажите, как сделать большое 3д облако в libgdx?
знаю, что с помощью шейдеров, делаю на плоскости, но, выглядят они как 2д,типа как на изображении, спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]